# Unexpected Proc Summary results

Tags: summary

I am trying to run a proc summary statement in SAS EG.  Below is my code.

```
proc summary data = SC_Rx_claims;
var PLAN_SCRIPT_COUNT AMOUNT_PAID;
output out = SC_Rx_Sum (drop=_type_ _freq_) SUM=;
run;
```

PLAN_SCRIPT_COUNT is a field that contains the numeric 1 for each entry.  But when I run the summary, I get an unexpected result of ** for PLAN_SCRIPT_COUNT.  I don't know what this means or what would cause it.  Does anyone have any insight into how resolve this or what ** means?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a format attached to `PLAN_SCRIPT_COUNT` in the source data and it is being carried forward into the output dataset.  Add a format statement to the PROC SUMMARY step to remove it and see if that helps.

```
proc summary data = SC_Rx_claims;
  var PLAN_SCRIPT_COUNT AMOUNT_PAID;
  format PLAN_SCRIPT_COUNT AMOUNT_PAID; 
  output out = SC_Rx_Sum (drop=_type_ _freq_) SUM=;
run;
```